# Mongoose schema does not create correct objects with the give attributes

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose not saving the correct Schema. Attributes are missing in the new- created object.

My schema is as follows:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users"
  },
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  dateOfBirth: {
    type: Date
  },
  expenses: {
    tyep: String
  },
  income: {
    type: String
  },
  experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  partner: {
    partnerIncome: {
      type: String
    },
    partnerExpenses: {
      tyep: String
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

And the code for creating a new object is :

```
new Profile(profileFields)
            .save()
            .then(profile => {
              //res.json(profileFields);
              res.json(profile);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.json(err);
            });
```

The data in profileFeild are as follows:

```
{
    "user": "5cbf0d03b6a1d33d085c5a41",
    "handle": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "dateOfBirth": "02/02/2019",
    "income": "600",
    "expenses": "300",
     "partnerIncome": "900",
     "partnerExpenses": "200"

}
```

The post successfully save as

```
{
    "partner": {
        "partnerIncome": "900"
    },
    "_id": "5cbfd9b2dc38893364f25063",
    "user": "5cbf0d03b6a1d33d085c5a41",
    "handle": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "dateOfBirth": "2019-02-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "income": "600",
    "experience": [],
    "education": [],
    "date": "2019-04-24T03:36:18.643Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Which we can see expenses and partnerExpenses are missing. How did this happen? And how to fix this problem?

If I use findOneAndUpdate to update, and then send the same profileFields data, all the fields will appear like the following(which is the expected result in the first time).

```
{
    "expenses": "300",
    "partner": {
        "partnerExpenses": "200",
        "partnerIncome": "900"
    },
    "_id": "5cbfd9b2dc38893364f25063",
    "user": "5cbf0d03b6a1d33d085c5a41",
    "handle": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "dateOfBirth": "2019-02-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "income": "600",
    "experience": [],
    "education": [],
    "date": "2019-04-24T03:36:18.643Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

By the way, the code for updating is here:

```
Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
          { user: req.user.id },
          { $set: profileFields },
          { new: true }
        ).then(profile => res.json(profile));
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos

```
expenses: {
tyep: String
},
```

and another one is

```
partnerExpenses: {
  tyep: String
}
```

can you please try after fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all lets make the Partner income, partner expenses, expenses and income into Integer, or a Number in the schema definition.

and fix the typos in

```
expenses:{
tyep: String//must be spelt type
}
and
partnerExpenses:{
tyep: String//must be spelt type
}
```